# Warning about incompatible pointer types

Tags: c, pointers, types, warnings

I'm not understanding a warning towards my code. It seems simple, but I simple don't get it. Here is the problematic piece of code:

```
chunk* findChunk(chunk *ptr, int size)
{
    ...
    chunk *newNode = ptr->end + size;
    ...
}
```

chunk is a struct defined by me earlier:

```
typedef struct chunk
{
    int size;
    int available;
    struct chunk* next;
    char end[1];
} chunk;
```

And this is the warning I receive:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]<br>
chunk *newNode = ptr->end + size;
```

I can't uderstand, it is clear for me that newNode and ptr are the same type. What am I missing? Thank you guys.

Comment: `newNode` and `ptr` are of same type, but `ptr->end + size` (which has the same type as `ptr->end`) is of type `char *`.

Answer (score 4):

Incompatible warning types arise when you equate two pointers which have been declared to point to different types together. It's permissible, because perhaps you as the coder know that it will work, but it usually won't and that's why you get a warning.

In your code, you've defined the `end` field of the struct to be a 1x1 char array which has type `char *`, but in your first snippet, you're trying to equate it with `chunk *`. From your code, it looks like you might mean to be using `next` instead of `end`.

Also, I would strongly discourage the use of adding integers to pointers unless you're absolutely sure of what you're doing. And even then, there's probably safer, better ways of achieving whatever you're attempting.

Also also, why are you creating a char array with a single element? That seems odd to me.

Comment: it'a a pre-c99 pre gnu struct hack

Comment: It's not permissible, it's a constraint violation. A compiler must complain and may refuse to compile. A cast is required for that conversion. And what's wrong with pointer arithmetic?

Comment: I'm trying to implement the malloc function, managing the available (free) memory with a linked list. The user required some memory, but my chunk is larger than the memory asked. So in this piece of code, I'm trying to split this node in two. I don't know whether this explanation was clear or not. I just want that newNode point further, so I can split it. But I got what you said, thanks for the response.

The char end[1] was just to mark the end of the metadata (it comes before the actual memory to be allocated).

Comment: @mafso, there's nothing wrong per se with pointer arithmetic, it's just dangerous and not type-safe. There are cases where it will be much more efficient than the alternatives, but you have to be extra careful. If it's not in a critical loop, perhaps a decrease in efficiency is worth it for an increase in readability, maintainability and type-safety. As for incompatible pointers being permissible, I think I recall, perhaps falsely, having code "work" with a pointer type mismatch.

Comment: E.g. Gcc is quite permissive. For many constraint violations, it only gives warnings instead of errors by default. That doesn't mean your code is correct C. And arithmetic doesn't change a type, if at all, you had to warn against pointers in general (but as I said, they're typed and in most cases, you need a cast to convert them).

Comment: Fair enough. We would agree that even if it was correct C, it's bad C anyway.
I think I would actually warn somebody away from using pointers if there was a good way to avoid them in whatever they were doing. Pointers _are_ unsafe. It just so happens that they're also powerful and useful. Pointer arithmetic is worse because it's much easier to jump to the wrong memory address than to start in the wrong spot (maybe with the exception of NULL).